# Choice of DC-DC converter feedback voltage (0.8V vs 0.736V)

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, feedback

I am choosing a DC-DC Buck converter for my application (AP62200 family). The part in question is offered in 2 versions - one with 0.8V FB voltage (AP62200) and one with 0.736V (AP62200T). Is there some special meaning of 0.736V, or it is made in a way to offer interchangeability with some legacy or alternative manufacturer parts?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t look like there is anything really special about 0.736V from the datasheet. The only explanation I can think of for offering that option instead of the standard 0.8V option (which is the FB voltage on 4 out of the 5 total chip types) is that it may allow easier selection of feedback resistors for some standard output voltage - maybe 3.3V or 5.0V.
I don’t have time to check, but there are several online resistor divider calculators which give standard resistor values you might like to check.